# Is there any way to avoid "Debug Assertion Failed" Window in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, runtime-error, assert

This is the window that I want to prevent from showing when executing:

[image]

I know it is a bad practice but I am currently working on a code that collects all these exceptions and displays them in a different way, it would simply need the "Ignore" option to be executed automatically since the code is programmed so that right after I finished collecting the exception and can be processed

Comment: You could compile in release mode. Exceptions will still be thrown but it would be harder to debug.

Comment: Hint: Your Question is not generic for C++ but Microsoft VisualC++ specific

Comment: I am not a visualC++ expert, but googeling found e.g. that: https://www.codeguru.com/visual-studio/write-debug-output-to-console-window/ guess it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* be able to

```
#define NDEBUG
```

which ought to suppress this. Secondarily, try undefining

```
_DEBUG
```

as parts of the Windows API use that.

---

That said, I wouldn't do this: assertions are really there as a last resort and therefore are meant to help the programmer. If you want to handle an assertion in a different way then handle the situation that leads to it "by hand" before the assertion happens.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: yeap. and now the code does not die in those places, and execution follows to a new path which is now undefined. I am unsure if this is a good practice on code that is not fully debugged.